# get Flickr images depending on a search result

Tags: javascript, flickr

How to display certain images from Flickr depending on a file name.
I want to search images and show only the ones that are fitting in my search results.

Honestly this is a first time that I'm using Flickr and they really need to put some more examples in there.

Any idea where to start?

Comment: Have you checked this? http://mashupguide.net/1.0/html/ch08s07.xhtml

Comment: @Chris thank's Chris I'll take a look at it! Others feel free to post some examples if you know

Answer (score 3):

Here's a helper method I threw together that lets you make a request to flickr's api. It would probably help to take a peek at the [flickr api documentation](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/) so you can start figuring out how to process the data you'll be getting back. This should work in Chrome and Firefox, I haven't tested it in IE or Safari.

```
/*
 * Make an XmlHttpRequest to api.flickr.com/services/rest/ with query parameters specified
 * in the options hash. Calls cb once the request completes with the results passed in.
 */

var makeFlickrRequest = function(options, cb) {
  var url, xhr, item, first;

  url = "http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/";
  first = true;

  for (item in options) {
    if (options.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
      url += (first ? "?" : "&") + item + "=" + options[item];
      first = false;
    }
  }

  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onload = function() { cb(this.response); };
  xhr.open('get', url, true);
  xhr.send();

};
```

**Usage:**

```
var options = { 
  "api_key": "<your api key here>",
  "method": "flickr.photos.search", // You can replace this with whatever method,
                                  // flickr.photos.search fits your use case best, though.
  "format": "json",
  "nojsoncallback": "1",
  "text": "<your search text here>"  // This is where you'll put your "file name"
}

makeFlickrRequest(options, function(data) { alert(data) }); // Leaving the actual 
                                                            // implementation up to you! ;)
```

If you're using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), here's a jQuery version:

```
var makeFlickrRequest = function(options, cb) {
  var url, item, first;

  url = "http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/";
  first = true;
  $.each(options, function(key, value) { 
    url += (first ? "?" : "&") + key + "=" + value;
    first = false; 
  });

  $.get(url, function(data) { cb(data); });

};
```

This method has the same usage as the non-jQuery version.

Comment: nice solution...I will try to use some of your code to see how will this work for me. I'll get back to you